# Como usar comillas simples cuando tengo texto en php

Tags: php

Hola es posible por ejemplo cuando escribo el siguiente codigo:

```
$content=' //incluir texto con comillas simples l'informatique por ejemplo ';
```

Esque uso comillas simples y aveces agrego texto desde php y obviamente se me corta hay alguna forma?
Mi pregunta es bastante simple por lo que no creo que tenga que dar mas detalles.

Comment: Pon doble comilla simple, en tu caso `$content=' //incluir texto con comillas simples l''informatique por ejemplo '';`

Comment: @OmarAlami En que sentido, en el ejemplo muestras tres comillas simples desde hay ya genere error. Añade el código que se corta con las comillas simples para ver el error?

Comment: ya esta puesto el codigo

Comment: @OmarAlami Ok revisa mi respuesta, pero en resumen el problema esta que solo muestras 3 comillas simples en un texto u contenido dividido. Saludos :)

Answer (score 4):

Pues te puedo dar opciones:

```
//OPCION 1
 $content="//incluir texto con comillas simples l'informatique por ejemplo ";


//OPCION 2
 $content2='//incluir texto con comillas simples l\'informatique por ejemplo ';
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el ejemplo que muestras solo tiene 3 comillas simples en un texto que estas dividiendo.

Remplazar:

```
  $content = ' //incluir texto con comillas simples l'informatique por ejemplo ';
```

Por:

```
  $content = ' //incluir texto con comillas simples l' 'informatique por ejemplo ' ';
```

---

**Ejemplo:**

```
  $x=' Aqui puede haber " dentro de la cadena';
  $x=" Aqui puede haber ' dentro de la cadena";
```

En el primer caso la comilla simple ' abre y cierra la cadena por lo que es posible meter una " comilla doble en la misma.

El segundo caso es el inverso, pones una comilla simple ' dentro del bloque abierto y cerrado por comillas dobles "

> **Documentación:**  ¿Cúando utilizar comillas simples y dobles en PHP?

- [Comillas simples y dobles](http://blog.tednologia.com/comillas-simples-y-dobles-en-php/)
- [Comillas simples](http://pixelar.me/comillas-simples-o-dobles-en-php/)
- [Sin comillas](http://s1.accesoperu.com/wp6/wp6.php?p=15542)

Answer (score 0):

Usa comillas dobles. Asi podras usar las simples dentro sin ningun problema. De tosdas formas, es recomendable usar la doble para cuando empieces a meter variables.

```
$content=" //incluir texto con comillas simples l'informatique por ejemplo ";
```