# Error en imprimir dato echo - PHP

Tags: php

Estoy imprimiendo una **Urls** con varios datos en un solo `echo` la url a imprimir es: `http://localhost/prueba/profile.php` y los valores de las variables son: **$url =** `http://` **$host =** `localhost` **APP-RAIZ =** `prueba`

Trate de la siguiente forma pero me imprime un error:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url $host APP_RAIZ.' profile.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>';
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$host' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\header.php on line 53

Trate de la siguiente forma pero también me imprime un error:

```
echo "<a href="'.$url $host APP_RAIZ.' profile.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>";
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$url $host; APP_RAIZ;.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\header.php on line 54

De la siguiente forma también pero sin resultado.

```
echo '<a href=" '.$url.' '.$host.' '.APP_RAIZ;.' login.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>';
```

He realizado otro tipo de impresión de varias datos en un solo `echo` sin ningún error, no veo donde estoy haciendo mal en imprimir la **url**

```
echo'<img src="img/upload/'.$pro['image'].'" alt="'.$pro['profile'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que se muestra son por errores de syntax (sintaxis) en el ultimo intento estuviste a una milesima de lograrlo pero te equivocaste en un solo detalle.

En el intento 1

```
echo '<a href="'.$url $host APP_RAIZ.' profile.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>';
```

> Falto añadir lo siguiente `'..'` en cada variable que contenía datos

En el ultimo intento

```
echo '<a href=" '.$url.' '.$host.' '.APP_RAIZ;.' login.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>';
```

> Ya lo tenias por un detalle te imprio el error, debías haber quitado lo siguiente `;` a `APP_RAIZ`

**La solución**

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.''.$host.''.APP_RAIZ.'profile.php">Profile</a>';
```

> Algunas referencias de mucha utilidad

- [Imprimir variables y cadenas en PHP, comillas simples o dobles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92944/imprimir-variables-y-cadenas-en-php-comillas-simples-o-dobles)
- [Como usar comillas simples cuando tengo texto en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24037/como-usar-comillas-simples-cuando-tengo-texto-en-php/24042#24042)
- [¿Cómo crear espacios y saltos de línea en PHP con comillas simples?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97752/c%C3%B3mo-crear-espacios-y-saltos-de-l%C3%ADnea-en-php-con-comillas-simples)